# Does not display Cyrillic in jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

I work in jupyter notebook and an error occurs when exporting a file to pdf. The Cyrillic alphabet is not displayed in the file. How to fix it?

I tried to create my own template, which is located in share\jupyter\nbconvert\templates\latex, but it didn't help.

[image: MyTemplate]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you check if your template is being used by looking at the generated latex file?

Comment: what to do if it is not used

Comment: `jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to latex --log-level DEBUG` would show where jupyter looks for templates and resulting tex file would either contain your template directives or not.

Comment: I looked at debug, it shows the path in which the template is stored, but still the Cyrillic alphabet is not visible

Comment: You could specify your template file explicitly with `jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to latex --template-file=share\jupyter\nbconvert\templates\latex\mytemplate.tex.j2`. Also please post the contents of your template file verbatim instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

By default Jupyter uses XeLaTeX to compile latex files and to convert notebooks to PDF. XeLaTeX is an alternative LaTeX engine with inbuilt support of Unicode, while PDFLaTeX requires encoding tricks in order to emit characters in characters other than basic ASCII encoding.

With XeLaTeX you do not need to load the `fontenc` package but you do need to ensure that the fonts XeLaTeX uses contain Cyrillic glyphs.

Here is a modification of your template that uses **Liberation** fonts that contain Cyrillic letters. If you do not have these fonts (as you are probably on Windows) you might experiment with other fonts.

```
((=- Default to the notebook output style -=))
((*- if not cell_style is defined -*))
((*- endif -*))

((=- Inherit from the specified cell style. -=))
((* extends 'base.tex.j2' *))

((* block docclass *))
\documentclass{article}
((* endblock docclass *))

((* block maketitle *)) ((* endblock maketitle *))

((* block packages *))
((( super() ))) % load all other packages
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Liberation Serif}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
((* endblock packages *))
```

To try this template you may run the following commands from the command line:

```bash
jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb --to latex --template-file=./mytemplate.tex.j2
xelatex novosibirsk_stations.tex
```